# 401 Unauthorized error on ajax call laravel 5.2

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

when i am doing ajax call i am getting error as 401 Unauthorized.

this is my ajax code:

```
var email=document.getElementById( "email" ).value;
  if(email)
  {
      var data = 'email='+ email;
      $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              dataType: "json",
              data: {"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}","data":data},
              url: "{{ URL::to('admin/check_email_exit') }}",
              success: function (response) {
              if(response=="1")
              {
                  $( '#email_status' ).html('Email Already Exists');
                  return false;
              }
              else
              {
                  $( '#email_status' ).html("");
                  return false;
              }
       }
       });
  }
    else
    {
         $( '#email_status' ).html("");
         return false;
    }
```

my route:

```
Route::post('admin/check_email_exit', 'CompanyController@check_email_exit');
```

this is my controller code that checks email exits or not:

```
public function check_email_exit(){
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $user_email = DB::table('users')->where('email',$email)->select('*')->get();
        $use_email=count($user_email);
        if($use_email > 0 )
        {
            return "1";
        }
        else
        {
            return "0";
        }
    }
```

how to resolve this error..??

Comment: Please post your server-side code as well

Comment: which middleware have you assign to route??..Route::post('admin/check_email_exit', 'CompanyController@check_email_exit');

Comment: @MayankMajithya i dont know about middleware

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware, please look middleware functionality here

Comment: 401 error is a middleware error. you should see if you have access to that route you are requesting

Answer (score 3):

Just set `X-CSRF-Token` in ajax Request header

```
headers: {
  'X-CSRF-Token': {{ csrf_token() }}
}
```

This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you need the route that you are calling, the user must be authorized or not. If the case is not, than you can try to define the route outside of **auth** middleware. Something like this.

Before:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::get('route_name', [Controller::class, 'methd']);
    ... other routes
});
```

After:

```
Route::get('route_name', [Controller::class, 'methd']);

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    ... other routes
});
```